# Blender vs Unity3d image quality

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, blender

I know that Blender and Unity3D are completely different software applications. Nevertheless, there are some overlaps: both perform rendering.

I am looking for a comparison between a model rendered in Blender and that same model rendered with Unity3D. I've looked about the net, but everything points to issues people are having with the quality of a model imported into Unity3d.

Anyone have any insight?

Comment: this is not a specific enough question. please provide details - which part of rendering do you mean? lighting? reflection? shadows? From FAQ: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." In addition to that, I personally think this question has better odds at gamedev.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Blender and Unity3d are free environmens, so you can quite easily produce a comparison yourself. 
The main difference is that Unity has a hard limit on time that can be spent on rendering each frame (33.3ms per frame is a maximum that enables 30fps display, you get 25fps with 40ms per frame) where as blender has no such limitantion and can spent virtually all the time you have preparing the result (often minutes per frame).
This luxury enables the renderer (i.e. Cycles) to perform more detailed rendering, taking more factors into account.
For example unity will only render a limited number of lights per object (4 as a default), sorting by the strength, and will fall back to a simpler method of light computation after that.

This means that generally blender will provide a better result, but will make you wait for it, while unity will present you with the output almost immediately while sacrificing a bit of the quality.

However, in both blender and unity the final quality is dependend mainly on the skill of the artist, and modern games using modern shader techniques (such as PBR) come closer and closer to the render quality of a modelling package by using smart optimisations and utilising newer design features of modern GPU hardware.

Comment: Great answer. Just want I wanted to know. Thank you!